# SwiftUI header font

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to find a good way to get the system font for a `List`'s header. Here's what I mean:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Test")) {
                Text("Blablabla")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Basically, is there a way to programmatically get the font for the text in the image that says "Test", so I can use it elsewhere in a `Text` object for example?

I'm font of the trying to make a collapsible header by using `DisclosureGroup`, however the font of the `DisclosureGroup` is different from the font of the `Section`.

Comment: By "get the font" do you mean figure out which font that is so you can use it elsewhere?

Comment: @gavinmccabe yes

Comment: Usually you can check using the Debug View Hierarchy, but it doesn't work well with SwiftUI...

Answer (score 2):

**For single use:**

```
Section(header: Text("Test").font(.title)) {
    Text("Blablabla")
}
```

**For multiple use:**

First, Create a struct:

```
struct CustomFont: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Test")
           .font(.title)
    }
 }
```

Second, Call the instance of the struct to use it.

```
Section(header: CustomFont()) {
    Text("Blablabla")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another approach is to give the font you want, and then use that everywhere you want to, lots of fun:

```
Text("Test").font(.largeTitle)

Text("Test").font(.system(size:34))

Text("Test").font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold, design: .serif)))

Text("Test").font(Font.custom("Wingdings", size: 30.0))

Text("Test").font(Font.custom("Montserrat-Bold", size: 30.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Section header's default font is `.font(.headline)`. And the text is uppercased.

```
Text("Test".uppercased()).font(.headline)
```

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/

[image]